# Ambiguity with variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, ambiguous

I've got a question regarding variadic templates. I've got a class that uses them in the following way:

```
template <class... T>
struct A {
  A(B& arg);                   // (1)
  A(typename T::B& args...);   // (2)
};
```

`typename T::B` is some type that is expected to be equal for all instances in the parameter pack. For ease of presentation, I refered to this type as `B`. The class contains an instance of `B` for each parameter in the parameter pack. The second constructor `(2)` initializes these members. For convenience, there is a constructor `(1)` that takes just one instance and initializes all members with the same instance.

The definition of the constructors is not really important for my problem, you can leave them empty. A more complete example is provided below.

Now, the problem is that the constructors conflict, if you initialize A with just one parameter. `g++-4.7` was a little confused here and bailed out, but after taking a closer look at the class the problem was obvious.

Questions:

1. What does the standard say about the situation? Is this an ambiguity that should / can be resolved by the compiler or am I supposed to avoid this situation?
2. What are the best strategies for avoiding it? Not specifying something like the first constructor at all? I could also put the functionality of the first constructor in a static method, but that would make the API more inhomogeneous.

Thanks for your answers!

---

Full example:

```
struct B {};

struct C
{
  using B = ::B;
};

template <class... T>
struct A
{
  A(B& arg) {}
  A(typename T::B & ... args) {}
};

int main()
{
  A<C> x(B()); // Edit: Should be: A<C> X{B()}; But not related to the problem.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB it would only be a variadic function if the ellipse were after a comma as if it were a parameter, like `A(typename T::B& args, ...);`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Oh, sorry, I misread the code. Never mind.

Comment: @Markus well which one do you want to be called when you do `A<B> x { B() }`?

Comment: @SethCarnegie In fact, I would not care in this case, because both constructors do the same. It would feel more natural, if the more specialized constructor, i.e. `(1)` would be called. But I assume that the best thing would be if the compiler failed (more gracefully than `g++` does now).

Comment: same underlying problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386042/confused-by-default-constructor-description-of-stdtuple-in-the-iso-c-standar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A<C> x(B());
```

Is a function declaration, not an object declaration. You need to add parens or use braces:

```
A<C> x { B() };
```

or

```
A<C> x((B()));
```

Also, to pass a temporary `B` to the constructor by reference, you have to make it `const`:

```
A(const B& arg) { }
```

Then

```
A<C> x((B()));
```

Works fine.

Now to address the ambiguity problem, you need something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct B {};

struct C
{
  using B = ::B;
};

template <class... T>
struct A
{
  A(const B& arg) {
    std::cout << "one" << std::endl;
  }

  template<bool IsNotOne = sizeof...(T) != 1>
  A(const typename std::enable_if<IsNotOne || !std::is_same<B, T>::value, T>::type::B&... args) {
    std::cout << "multiple" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<B> x1 { B() };         // prints one
  A<C> x2 { B() };         // prints one
  A<C, C> x3 { B(), B() }; // prints multiple
  A<B, B> x4 { B(), B() }; // prints multiple
  return 0;
}
```

We make the second constructor a template so we can rely on SFINAE.

Comment: I can't see how this resolves the ambiguity. Apart from that `A<C> x(B())` would only be considered as a function declaration at global scope? Furthermore, `B()` is not a type, therefore `A<C> X(B())` is not a function declaration.

Comment: @MarkusMayr function declarations are allowed at function scope, not just global. Also, `B()` is a valid way to declare a parameter (a function pointer). Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12590078/726361)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll take a look at it. But the problem remains the same, of course, even if I change that part of the code to `A<C> X{B()}` or `A<C> X((B()))`.

Comment: Great answer! I also learned something about SFINAE and constructors. Thanks!