# Why am I getting the error operator() cannot be overloaded?

Tags: c++

I have two overloads of `operator()`, one that takes a function reference that takes any type as its parameters and returns any type. And another one which takes a function reference that takes any type as its parameter but returns `void`. Upon instantiation of my class I get the following errors:

> `In instantiation of 'A<void, int>':`
>   `error: 'void A<T, F>::operator()(void (&)(F)) [with T = void, F = int]' cannot be overloaded`
>   `error: with 'void A<T, F>::operator()(T (&)(F)) [with T = void, F = int]'`

```
template <typename T, typename F> struct A {
    void operator()(T (&)(F)) {}
    void operator()(void (&)(F)) {}
};

void f(int) {}

int main() {

    A<void, int> a;
    a(f);
}
```

These errors only occur when the first template argument `T` is `void`. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and why I can't overload `operator()` this way?

Comment: You have defined two functions named `operator()` with identical signatures. What did you expect?

Comment: @n.m. If and only if `T` is `void` do I want to use the second `operator()` overload. That's basically what I was trying to do but Pubby cleared it up for me.

Comment: for the same reason why std::tuple has a broken constructor specification. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386042/confused-by-default-constructor-description-of-stdtuple-in-the-iso-c-standar

Comment: The language/compiler doesn't know which definition you want to use, so it flags an error. There's no easy way to tell the compiler "if there are two, I want to use this one", so you have to provide only one definition. Pubby's suggestion is one way to make sure there's only one; another way is to use SFINAE and something like `std::enable_if`. If your `struct A` ever grows too large to specialize conveniently, you may want to research this second option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if `T` is `void` then you have two function definitions with the exact same prototype - breaking ODR.

Try specializing your struct to prevent this:

```
template <typename T, typename F> struct A {
    void operator()(T (&)(F)) {}
    void operator()(void (&)(F)) {}
};

template <typename F> struct A<void, F> {
    void operator()(void (&)(F)) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Question: What is ODR?

Comment: @templateboy *[One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)